# How do I get my mac to re-scan for devices? -> Keyboard stops working after usb hub/dock with keyboard/mouse connected

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard, usb, trackpad

I have a Dock at home and work.  They both use versions of the pluggable usb 3.0 chipset.

Each dock has a keyboard and trackball attached.  When I move from one dock to another the   keyboard and trackpad on the Macbook stop working.  Is there a way to reset the device subsystem without rebooting?

```
Details that may be relevant:
  Model Name:         MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier:       MacBookPro11,2
  Processor Name:         Intel Core i7
  SMC Version (system):   2.18f6

  System Version:   OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 13.2.0
```

Could be related to [When reconnecting my laptop to an external monitor, the USB ports stop working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103116/when-reconnecting-my-laptop-to-an-external-monitor-the-usb-ports-stop-working), as I do use outlook.

Also similar to [Internal keyboard and trackpad stop working after plugging in USB device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119849/internal-keyboard-and-trackpad-stop-working-after-plugging-in-usb-device)

These questions do not ask how to reset the subsystem, which is a hack.  I can work around the issue if I know that piece of information.