# Internal keyboard stops working when usb keyboard plugged in

Tags: macos, keyboard

My MacBook Pro internal keyboard frequently stops working after an external USB keyboard has been plugged into it.  I have to do a hard reboot to recover (which I unfortunately need to do every time I transition from work to home).  Anybody have any suggestions on how to get around this?

Currently OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 is installed.

Similar to this problem: [How do I get my mac to re-scan for devices? -> Keyboard stops working after usb hub/dock with keyboard/mouse connected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132417/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-re-scan-for-devices-keyboard-stops-working-after-usb)

Comment: There may be a firmware update for your Mac and or external keyboard.  Have you checked for updates via the App Store?  What model is your MacBook Pro?  (Go to  > About this Mac) I.e.: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)  Also, what brand is your USB keyboard?  Apple, Logitec, etc.?  Cheers and welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: Model: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013).  Apple Keyboard.  No firmware updates are waiting in the App Store.  Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem; did you get anywhere with it?